# How to send order detail in another server when user place order?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to create observer on event sales_order_save_after but the event can't connect observer method. Please help me i am helpless?

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
        <Jeweldroship_Checkoutcomments>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Jeweldroship_Checkoutcomments>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
     <events>
       <sales_order_save_after>
         <observers>
            <jeweldroship_checkoutcomments>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>jeweldroship_checkoutcomments/observer</class>
                <method>salesOrderSaveAfter</method>
            </jeweldroship_checkoutcomments>
         </observers>
       </sales_order_save_after>
     </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My Observer.php

```
<?php 
class Jeweldroship_Checkoutcomments_Model_Observer
{ 
    public function salesOrderSaveAfter($observer) {
         $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
         $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
         $sql = "insert into mg_order_log set order_id='1',created=".time();
         $writeConnection->query($sql);
         echo "Product has been imported successfully.";
    }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't declare your model in config.xml

```
<global> 
  <models> 
    <model_alias> 
      <class>Youname_Yourmodulename_Model</class>
    </model_alias> 
   <!-- ... ---> 
  </models> 
</global>
```

Comment: I have added model in config.xml but i can't help on my code. <global>
        <models>
            <jeweldroship_checkoutcomments>
                <class>Jeweldroship_Checkoutcomments_Model</class>
            </jeweldroship_checkoutcomments>
        </models>
    </global>

Comment: What do you see in var/log/system or var/log/exeption?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define your `<events>` tag under `<frontend>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Jeweldroship_Checkoutcomments>
        <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
    </Jeweldroship_Checkoutcomments>
</modules>
<global>
<events>
  <sales_order_save_after>
    <observers>
        <jeweldroship_checkoutcomments>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>jeweldroship_checkoutcomments/observer</class>
            <method>salesOrderSaveAfter</method>
        </jeweldroship_checkoutcomments>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
</global>
</config>
```